# Running a loop through records in a batch with Azure Functions Python

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-queues

I'm new to Azure . I need to trigger a azure function for each record . I'm able to do it in a loop but this becomes a sequential process taking time and resulting in a time-out . Rather I want it done in a parallel processing mode .

My approach so far .

1. Create a Queue and push each record from the database to the queue .
2. Trigger the function based on the message getting added to the queue .

This setup works fine but I feel that inserting the records into the queue in itself is a sequential process . Is there a different way to do this . Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to trigger the function for each record, queue storage trigger is a good option. You can improve your approach in two aspects.

**Azure function part**

You can configure in **host.json** to control queue processing. The `queues.batchSize` knob is how many queue messages are fetched at a time.

```
"queues": {
      // The maximum interval in milliseconds between
      // queue polls. The default is 1 minute.
      "maxPollingInterval": 2000,
      // The visibility timeout that will be applied to messages that fail processing
      // (i.e. the time interval between retries). The default is zero.
      "visibilityTimeout" : "00:00:30",
      // The number of queue messages to retrieve and process in
      // parallel (per job function). The default is 16 and the maximum is 32.
      "batchSize": 16,
      // The number of times to try processing a message before
      // moving it to the poison queue. The default is 5.
      "maxDequeueCount": 5,
      // The threshold at which a new batch of messages will be fetched.
      // The default is batchSize/2. Increasing this value will increase the
      // level of concurrency and therefore throughput. New batches of messages
      // will be pulled until the number of messages being processed is greater
      // than this threshold. When the number dips below this threshold, new
      // batches will be fetched.
      "newBatchThreshold": 8
    }
```

Reference:

[host.json settings for queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-output?tabs=csharp#hostjson-settings)

**Your code part**

You can use multi-threaded code to insert the records into the queue.

Reference:

[threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

[How to use threading in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-can-i-use-threading-in-python)

Comment: Hi. Thanks or the suggestions . It helped.

Comment: Hi , I did hit another trouble when I deployed this function . Posted it as a question 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62217881/azure-queue-trigger-function-not-firing